# Error when trying to read excel files in a loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops

I'm storaging data from each training session (as a personal trainer) with the training variables. I send a copy of an .xlsx file with the name of the client, the day and month.

However I get an error message when trying to read with pandas in a loop.
The loop is to read each file in the directory and storage it in an .npy file in the end of the day.

The part of the code im having trouble is:

```
import os
pasta = os.listdir('path')
if pasta[-1] == 'desktop.ini':
        pasta.remove(pasta[-1])
os.chdir('path')
x = 0
while x < len(pasta):
        ler = pd.read_excel(pasta[x])
        ler = np.array(pd.read_excel(pasta[x]))
        string = pasta[x].strip('.xlsx')
        string = string.replace('_', '1')
        y = 0
        #Loop to remove the data to get the directory
        while y < len(string):
            if string[-1].isnumeric() == True:
                string = string.strip(string[-1])
            y = y + 1
        np.save(path, ler)
        x = x + 1
```

The error message i get is this:

> xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'[.ShellC'

I have NO truble reading the .xlsx files when the code is not in a loop. I tried opening it just the same before the loop and the error is raised only in the loop.

Comment: Use `print(pasta[x])` in the beginning of the loop to see at which file the reading fails. There is probably a bad character there.

Comment: include the full traceback of the error or tell us exactly what line is giving you the problem. You can also try adding an `if not pasta[x].endswith('.xlsx'): continue` (perhaps a hidden file in the folder?), and printing the filename as suggested

Comment: If out of loop, i am able to open `pasta[x]`.
The line of problem is `ler = np.array(pd.read_excel(pasta[x]))`. If i copy this line and run out of loop, it runs ok. The problem is that i close the day with something like 5 to 7 .xlsx files in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I think is you might have some non excel files. You need to make a check for your files ending with 'xlsx'

```
import os
pasta = os.listdir('path')
if pasta[-1] == 'desktop.ini':
        pasta.remove(pasta[-1])
os.chdir('path')
x = 0
while x < len(pasta):
    if pasta[x].endswith('xlsx'):
        ler = pd.read_excel(pasta[x])
        ler = np.array(pd.read_excel(pasta[x]))
        string = pasta[x].strip('.xlsx')
        string = string.replace('_', '1')
        y = 0
        #Loop to remove the data to get the directory
        while y < len(string):
            if string[-1].isnumeric() == True:
                string = string.strip(string[-1])
            y = y + 1
       np.save(path, ler)
       x = x + 1
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem was with 'desktop.ini'.. I assumed it was on the end of the list and it wasnt.. Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem, let me know in case you need any help.